# “My mother played soccer”

Tags: meaning-in-context

First, even though the juice was water, if I didn’t drink the juice but drank the water, I cannot say I drank the juice.

Likewise, if when my mother wasn’t a mother, she played soccer, cannot I say my mother played soccer but should I say my mother was a girl who played soccer?

Is there no need to relate the timing cues of the relationship in that noun phrase to the verb phrase?

Comment: I think you must have been drinking *something* to come up with that first sentence. But to your question, have you ever heard the term "mother's maiden name"? What does that tell you about how to refer to something that happened in your mother's life before she became a mother?

Comment: @nnnnnn Her name was Kim.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "My mother played soccer when she was a girl."

Comment: My mother was in the (UK) Royal Air Force from 1939 to 1945. She was not 'a mother' yet, but it makes sense to call her mother. My grandfather joined the Navy at the age of 14.

Comment: People frequently say that their parents were born overseas. No one is born a parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“My mother” is a noun phrase built on a current relationship. “Played soccer” is a verb phrase relating to the previous noun phrase. There is no need to relate the timing cues of the relationship in that noun phrase to the verb phrase.

If this was not so, your suggestion of “My mother was a girl who played soccer” would also not work for the same reason: when she was a soccer-playing girl, she wasn’t (yet) your mother.

Comment: Then, “I drank the juice when the juice was water” is also correct?

Comment: How can water become juice? Your first example is logical nonsense (unless you have a better explanation of what you mean!).

Comment: @user284848 Grammatically, it’s fine, but the water/juice example doesn’t make sense. You can say “I met my boss when he was just a baby” because meeting him didn’t stop him from becoming your boss. But if you’re referring to water taken up by a plant that turns it into juice in its fruit, then drinking that water would have deprived the plant of it. (You can argue for returning the water in various ways, but that’s a separate matter.)